# How to Get the Address of the Pointer in a com_ptr_t

Tags: c++, com, null, direct3d, smart-pointers

I need to pass the address of my ID3D11RenderTargetView pointer to a function, and I use a com_ptr_t to hold it. So first I tried:

```
ID3D11RenderTargetViewPtr pRenderTargetView; = ID3D11RenderTargetViewPtr(NULL);
pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pRenderTargetView, nullptr);
```

However, the & operator turns the pointer to null. I then went over the com_ptr_t functions again and saw that I could write:

```
pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pRenderTargetView.GetInterfacePtr(), nullptr);
```

It does work, but isn't there a simpler way to get the address of the underlying pointer without losing it? By simpler, I mean shorter, syntax wise.

Comment: No, these are the only two ways. `_com_ptr_t` is a pretty simple class, you can see its definition in `comip.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Igor's comment is correct.  The purpose of `_com_ptr_t` is pretty straightforward, and trivial conversion to raw interface pointers is almost always the wrong thing to do.

For example, the primary reason why the `&` operator releases the interface is that the number one reason people take the address of a smart pointer is to pass it as an out parameter to some factory function.  If the `&` didn't release the pointer, then the old value would leak.

This happened *a lot*.

Now, there are much rarer cases, such as the one you have, where you pass the address of an interface to a function that isn't going to set it, and in those cases, you have the GetInterfacePtr function.